# How to dynamically set the item height inside the listview?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I was trying to set the Items height of a ListView.

What I want is like:

set the first item's height to 10

set the second item's height to 20

set the third item's height to 30

set the four item's height to 15

In order to achieve this goal, I try to set the layout of 'convertView' inside getView method
[image]

I have tried some methods(don't work):

1. `//         LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams();
   //          layoutParams.height = 30;
   //          timeTableCellViewHolder.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`
2. `//timeTableCellViewHolder.getLayoutParams().height = 30;
           //convertView.getLayoutParams().height = 30;`
   This method returns a nullPoint exception, The View object seens don't got a height para.
3. `//timeTableCellViewHolder.setMinimumHeight(50);`

These are some of my code:

1. getView of BaseAdapter
   [image]
2. xml layout of Item inside listview
   [image]
3. layout of activity that contain this list view
   [image]

Comment: Is there any fix order in which you want to change the height?

Comment: My height is drived by data source, when the data source changed, height should change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position)

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 4;
}
```

Hope that helps. Cheers